# I was wondering how to make a leaderboard cmd in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord.py

Hi I was wondering how I would make a leaderboard cmd in discord.py rewrite I have a fully working lvling system but I'm wondering how to show the top ten ppl that are the highest lvl. I tried this but nothing comes up when I type -leaderboard ok so I need to type more to upload this so just ignore what I'm typing now damn I need to write even more ok is this enough hopfully

```
async def leaderboard(ctx):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        # add 1 to postion to make the index start from 1
        names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> with {top_users[user]}\n'

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard")
    embed.add_field(name="Names", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

in my users.json folder its user id then xp then lvl.

here is the code for my mainfile

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        users = json.load(f)

    await update_data(users, member)

    with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(users, f)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
        await level_up(users, message.author, message)

        with open('users.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    await client.process_commands(message)


async def update_data(users, user):
    if not f'{user.id}' in users:
        users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1


async def add_experience(users, user, exp):
    users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp


async def level_up(users, user, message):
    with open('levels.json', 'r') as g:
        levels = json.load(g)
    experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
    lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
    lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
        await message.channel.send(f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}')
        users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end

@client.command()
async def level(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        id = ctx.message.author.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'You are at level {lvl}!')
    else:
        id = member.id
        with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)
        lvl = users[str(id)]['level']
        await ctx.send(f'{member} is at level {lvl}!')
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that commands in discord.py should use [the command decorator](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=command#decorators) to specify that the function is meant to be processed as a command.

Therefore, in your main file, please add:

```py
@client.command()
async def leaderboard(ctx):

    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    top_users = {k: v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)}

    names = ''
    for postion, user in enumerate(top_users):
        # add 1 to postion to make the index start from 1
        names += f'{postion+1} - <@!{user}> with {top_users[user]}\n'

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Leaderboard")
    embed.add_field(name="Names", value=names, inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The `client.command()` decorator has been added here.

Comment: idk if im dumb and do know how to use it but i added it to my main.py file and when I write -leaderboard nothing happens no errors just nothing it would be great if you could help me

Comment: it would be great if you would answer my question asap